# How do I avoid the 'ZeroDivisionError: division by zero' error when a user enters a string the first two instances using my code below?

Tags: python

```
nums = []

while True:
    user_resp = input('Enter a number:')

    try:
        if user_resp == 'done':
            break
        if user_resp == 'DONE':
            break
        num = float(user_resp)
        nums.append(num)
    except:
        if user_resp == 'abort':
            exit()
        if user_resp == 'ABORT':
            print('aborting...')
            exit()
        else:
            print('Invalid Input.Type done to calculate or abort to exit.')
avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
print('Average:', avg)
```

Comment: Erm, why don't you just check that you divide by zero?

Comment: You are abusing `try/except`. It should be used only around the statements that are likely to fail.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think you understand the purpose of`try... except` statement. It's supposed to catch errors--your code doesn't seem to suggest that.

Comment: DYZ - how do you mean 'abusing'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nums = []

while True:
    user_resp = input('Enter a number: ')

    try:
        if user_resp.lower() == 'done':
            break
        elif user_resp.lower() == 'abort':
            print('aborting...')
            exit()
        num = float(user_resp)
        nums.append(num)

    except:
        print('Invalid Input.Type done to calculate or abort to exit.')
try:
    avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    print('Average:', avg)
except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
    print('Cannot divide by zero')
```

Is this what you are looking for? I've also streamlined your code to get rid of unnecessary checks

Answer (score 0):

Check for zero:

```
nums = []

while True:
    user_resp = input('Enter a number:')

    try:
        if user_resp == 'done':
            break
        if user_resp == 'DONE':
            break
        num = float(user_resp)
        nums.append(num)
    except:
        if user_resp == 'abort':
            exit()
        if user_resp == 'ABORT':
            print('aborting...')
            exit()
        else:
            print('Invalid Input.Type done to calculate or abort to exit.')
if len(nums) == 0:
    print('No numbers provided')
else:
    avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    print('Average:', avg)
```

Comment: More "Pythonic": `if nums:` or `if not nums:`.

Comment: my 2nd week in learning python.... i haven't seen an if-else outside a loop. i learned something from you. thanks!